# get selected file name with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show selected file name in file input by JavaScript but not sure how to

[image: one]

I want change `No file selected` with file name

## Code

```
<div class="upload-info mt-2"><strong>Attachment</strong> <span>Max. file size: 3MB</span></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<label class="upload-btn">
  {{Form::file('attachment', array('id' => 'attachment'))}}
  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Browse
</label>
<span class="fake-input">No file selected</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#fake-input').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#attachment").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });
    });
</script>
```

what should i change in my code?

## Update

```
<label class="upload-btn">
  {{Form::file('attachment', array('id' => 'attachment'))}}
  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Browse
</label>
<span class="fake-input">No file selectedspan</span>
<span id="fake-input"></span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.fake-input').hide();
                    $('#fake-input').append(e.target.result).show();
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#attachment").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
            $('#fake-input').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

## error

getting `data:image/jpeg;base64,.............` instead of file name

Comment: that span has a class, your selecting it with id selector, ofcourse it wont work

Comment: @ChrisLi thanks i fixed that and changed `attr` with append now i get image data not the name of file

Comment: @ChrisLi updated

Comment: try doing `input.files[0].name` instead of `e.target.result`

Comment: @NickParsons it gets the name but not replace with old one it just add up `1 zj5V26kqQ4s2Yp-D1d6YjA.jpeg02.jpeg23.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Thanks for everyone who commented and helped me realize the mistakes, here is latest edits (working code) for  those in need.

> PS: I commented parts that i thought it's worth to notice.

`script`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.fake-input').hide(); // hiding default text (image above)
                    $('#fake-input').append(input.files[0].name).show(); //replace with name of file
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#attachment").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
            $('#fake-input').empty(); // avoid of duplicate when file changes
        });
    });
</script>
```

`html`

```
<label class="upload-btn">
  {{Form::file('attachment', array('id' => 'attachment'))}}
  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Browse
</label>
<span class="fake-input">No file selectedspan</span>
<span id="fake-input" class="fake-input"></span> //display none by css
```

Comment: Just posting code isn't very helpful, you should explain what you changed and how it fixed your issue. Consider reducing the code to an absolute minimum (maybe 3 or 4 lines) to show the issue.

Comment: You are literally doing nothing with this FileReader. Please remove it: It will load the whole file in memory twice + create access to disk while the information you were trying to access has been given by the OS directly.

Comment: @RobG the fix part i commented in code, and thanks for advice i just published whole code for newbies so they not get confused, experts are the ones who helped me no need more explain :)

Comment: @Kaiido you mean i should replace my render var with something else? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: I mean that all the FileReader part is useless, and will consume memory and CPU for nothing. `function readURL(input) {   $('.fake-input').hide();  $('#fake-input').append(input.files[0].name).show();}` is all you really need. But place your `$('#fake-input').empty();` before you do call readURL since from now on, it will change the DOM synchronously.

Comment: If the OP uses `.text()` instead of `.append()` then *empty* is redundant. This has become a jQuery question…